# How to perform app check with Pyrebase using Python?

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase, firebase-app-check

I cannot find the appropriate method to call for `firebase.appCheck()` equivalent in Pyrebase library.

Answer (score 1):

As covered in the [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) documentation, currently the only first-party supported App Check providers for Firebase are DeviceCheck (on iOS), App Attest (on iOS) SafetyNet (on Android) and reCAPTCHA v3 (for web apps).

If you want to support Python, you'd have to develop/find some way to generate a signature for your script/program and follow the documentation on how to create a [Custom App Check Provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-provider) which could be hosted on a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).